# What is the name given to Wahi writers?

Tags: quran

Salam,

I read in a book that when wahi was revealed to the prophet, some of his companions used to write down the wahi. The book mentions that these companions are called "Kuththabul Wahi" .

I couldn't verify this name from another source .

Is this correct ?

Jazakallahu Khair

Answer (score 1):

Scribe of revelation - كاتب الوحي